# conditional prop react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am using react-select as my select component and i have multi prop there, but what i want to happen is that if multi prop is true i want `onChange` argument to be array of options, otherwise `OptionType`, i am using discriminated unions for that, but it does not seem to work properly

```
type OptionType<T> = {
  value: T;
  label: string;
};

interface CommonProps<T> {
  ...props
  options: Array<OptionType<T>>;
  value: ValueType<OptionType<T>, boolean>;
}

type ValueProps<T> = {
  multi: false;
  handler: (arg0: OptionType<T> | null) => any;
};

type MultiValueProps<T> = {
  multi: true;
  handler: (arg2: OptionsType<OptionType<T>> | null) => void;
};

type Props<T> = CommonProps<T> & (ValueProps<T> | MultiValueProps<T>);
```

now problem is that typescript gives me this

> Argument of type 'OptionType | OptionsType<OptionType> | null'
> is not assignable to parameter of type '(OptionType &
> OptionsType<OptionType>) | null'.

and this is the type of value parameter returned from `onChange`

```
(parameter) e: OptionType<T> | OptionsType<OptionType<T>> | null
```

for some reason typescript conjoins `handler` function arguments, i've tried this technique and it works with `never` or if i use different prop name for handlers, but i want it to have same names

Comment: Can you please create your problem example in codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-volhard-uukxj?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: what do you think the problem is

Comment: The codesandbox you posted doesn't contain the error that you mentioned in the OP

Comment: it's on line 63

Comment: `onChange={(e) => props.handler(e /*<- this has red underline*/)}`

Comment: isn't it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually make this much easier with [Generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). The general strategy is to make the type of the props object generic on the value of `isMulti`. For completeness, we also consider `isClearable` for completeness to know if we should include `null` in our change handler. Note that this only works for values of `isMulti` and `isClearable` that are known at compile-time to be only true or only false. This is true when giving a constant value to those props, which is most often the case.

First, we make a new generic type `MySelectProps` which represents the contract we need to follow when pairing up values of `isMulti`, `isClearable` and `onChange`:

```
type SelectProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Select>;
type SelectPropsWithoutOnChange = Pick<
  SelectProps,
  // remove onChange from react-select's props type so we can override it below
  Exclude<keyof SelectProps, "onChange">
>;

// our generic type enforcing a relationship between isMulti, isClearable and onChange's parameter type
type MySelectProps<
  IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  IsClearable extends boolean = false
> = SelectPropsWithoutOnChange & {
  isMulti: IsMulti;
  isClearable?: IsClearable;
  onChange: (
    e:
      // if it is possible for isClearable to be true, union the param type with null
      | (true extends IsClearable ? null : never)
      // if isMulti can be true, must handle OptionsType
      | (true extends IsMulti ? OptionsType<OptionTypeBase> : never)
      // if isMulti can be false, must handle OptionType
      | (false extends IsMulti ? OptionType<OptionTypeBase> : never)
  ) => void;
};
```

Once this is done, we introduce a generic function component which takes these props and then passes them to react-select's Select component,
in the process asserting that this is a valid operation. This assertion is important because our prop type is not assignable to Select's prop type.

```
// we must use a function here so that it can be generic.
const MySelect = <IsMulti extends boolean, IsClearable extends boolean>(
  props: MySelectProps<IsMulti, IsClearable>
) => (
  // this type assertion is where this method is risky
  // you need to know for sure that Select follows the contract
  // implied by the type definition of MySelectProps
  <Select {...((props as any) as SelectProps)} />
);
```

You are now free to render `MySelect`:

```
const elem = <MySelect
  // need to include specifically if we aren't handling null
  isClearable={false}
  isMulti
  // this is now safe because isMulti is known statically
  // to be true, and isClearable to be false,
  // so e is inferred only as OptionsType<OptionTypeBase>
  onChange={(e) => e.slice}
  />;
```

If your `FormSelect` component is not always multi-select or always single-select, you can make it generic with `IsMulti` and/or `IsClearable` as necessary.

Note that if `isMulti` is passed a `boolean` expression which could be true or false, your `onChange` handler will then need to handle both cases.

Comment: amazing solution, though i do not understand `IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  IsClearable extends boolean = false` =, this part. why use `= false` ?

Comment: `= false` is just a default for the type parameter in case it's not specified or inferred from an expression - `= boolean` would be perhaps better (less specific by default). You can probably remove it if you don't explicitly type anything as `MySelectProps`.

Comment: @Iliaaaa did this answer solve your question? Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: it is worthy solution, although it is still bad to use any, but i think it should be accepted

Comment: @Iliaaaa there will always be at least one unsafe cast, because you're declaring a more strict type for the props. You can always pull-request the new definition into `@types/react-select` instead.